# Disable bootstrap buttons until after youtube video plays

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, youtube-api

This is being set up for a form, so I need the user to not be able to click the buttons regardless of what until the video finishes.

I am using the Youtube Video API to play a video, I have two buttons below the video that I want to stay disabled until the video finishes playing. The issue is that regardless of adding attribute, or even prop through jquery to keep them disabled. The button is still firing a click event.

I've also tried adding the disabled class to the anchor, but then what happens is that the buttons stay disabled and cannot be set to active even once the video is done and the active class is called through code.

Code I have for the video playing:

```
<!--YOUTUBE VIDEO SCRIPT-->
    <script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // create youtube player
        var player;

        function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player( 'player', {
                height: '315',
                width: '560',
                videoId: 'i1XKt2T8ejc',
                events: {

                    onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange
                }
            } );
        }

        // when video ends
        function onPlayerStateChange( event ) {
            if ( event.data === 0 ) {
                /*Accept and Decline buttons are selectable once video plays entirely*/
                $( 'a.yes' ).attr( 'disabled', false);
                $( 'a.no' ).attr( 'disabled', false);
            }

        }
    </script>
```

Other code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $( 'a.yes' ).attr( 'disabled', true);
 $( 'a.no' ).attr( 'disabled', true);
</script>
```

Buttons:

```
<a href="exit.php" role="button" class="btn btn-danger no" style="float:right; width:100px;" >Decline</a>

<a href="yes.php" role="button" class="btn btn-success yes"  style="float:right; width:100px;">Accept</a>
```

Comment: Couple of questions: 1. have you verified that the "onPlayerStateChange" function is actually getting called? 2. You mention about the buttons still firing events, but do they visually appear disabled or not?

Comment: @ChrisCousins Yes the function was getting called and the buttons visually appeared disabled. The below answer solved though, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work, however you can't disable an `a` element; change it to a button.

```
<button href="exit.php" role="button" class="btn btn-danger no" style="float:right; width:100px;" >Decline</abutton>

<button href="yes.php" role="button" class="btn btn-success yes"  style="float:right; width:100px;">Accept</button>
```

and for the jQuery to

```
$( 'button.yes' ).attr( 'disabled', true);
$( 'button.no' ).attr( 'disabled', true);
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved it, it's always something simple haha

Comment: @user3015009 totally. Took me a while to notice it as well ;)